# Angular - how to make $interval work from user input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am taking date and time from user as input and then wanted to display it interval in label
After that datetime completes I want to make that label color change.

Please guide me how can i achieve this.

https://codepen.io/shreyag020/pen/vKvmdx

```
$interval(function(){
todoTime=$scope.datetime;
});
```

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: $interval(function(){

});

Comment: I mean about the behavior you expect. The codepen is confuse.

Comment: what should I write inside it so that the date and time the user enters run in interval of 1000 and when that competes it shows some message

Comment: This is not working $interval(function(){
$scope.todoTime=$scope.datetime;
},1000);

Comment: please reply for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could change the background color of a div over time. Clicking the start button begins a countdown timer from 1 minute. It starts out with no background, once the timer is started it turns green, at 15 seconds before time runs out it turns orange and when the time has run out it turns red. The change of the background color is animated using `ng-class`, `ngAnimate` and the animation hooks.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    var timerPromise;
  
    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.userTime = new Date;
      $scope.userTime.setMinutes(1);
      $scope.userTime.setSeconds(0);
      $scope.resetVisible = false;
      $scope.started = false;
    }

    $scope.start = function() {
      $scope.started = true;
      $scope.resetVisible = false;
      timerPromise = $interval(function() {
        if ($scope.userTime.getSeconds() > 0 || $scope.userTime.getMinutes() > 0) {
          $scope.userTime.setTime($scope.userTime.getTime() - 1000);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    
    $scope.pause = function() {
      $interval.cancel(timerPromise);
      $scope.started = false;
      $scope.resetVisible = true;
    }

    $scope.timeBackground = function() {
      if ($scope.started) {
        if ($scope.userTime.getMinutes() === 0 && $scope.userTime.getSeconds() === 0) {
          $scope.resetVisible = true;
          $interval.cancel(timerPromise);
          return 'expired';
        }
        if ($scope.userTime.getMinutes() === 0 && $scope.userTime.getSeconds() <= 15) {
          return 'warning';
        }
        return 'ok';
      }
      return 'clear';
    }

    $scope.reset();
  });
```

```css
.timeDisplay {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ok-add,
.ok-remove,
.warning-add,
.warning-remove,
.expired-add,
.expired-remove {
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
.warning,
.warning-add.pre-warning-add-active {
  background-color: orange;
}
.expired,
.expired-add.expired-add-active {
  background-color: red;
}
.ok,
.ok-add.ok-add-active {
  background-color: green;
}
.clear {
  background-color: none;
  color: black;
}
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="timeDisplay" ng-class="timeBackground()">
    Time remaining: {{userTime | date: 'mm:ss'}}
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!started">
    <button ng-click="start()">Start</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="started">
    <button ng-click="pause()">Pause</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="resetVisible">
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have got your date from  new date; My date is taken from user input how should I display that

Comment: Yes. You should be able to easily modify that to suit your needs by passing in the date. e.g. `$scope.startDate = new Date(<pass your date here>);`

Comment: $interval(function() {
      $scope.currentTime = new Date;
    }, 1000);                                                                                                     what should I write inside the function?

Comment: That is showing the current time. All that function does is run once each second to update the current time being displayed.

Comment: @shreyagupta I've changed the code to demonstrate a countdown timer.